# iOS - Change View with the device orientation

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, orientation-changes

I'm using iOS5 and storyboard. I have two view with two different identifier.
I want change the view when change the orientation of the device.
This is my code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

    if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || 
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))){

        self.view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Landscape"];

    }
    else if(((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || 
              (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))){

        self.view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Portrait"];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

But the app crash.
Which is the problem?

EDIT:
If I add two uiview and I put the two id to the uiview when I rotate the device It crash.
This is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

}

- (void) orientationChanged:(id)object
{  
    portraitView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermoregolatoreTop"];
    landscapeView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Landscape"];

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {

        self.view = self.portraitView;
    } 
    else 
    {

        self.view = self.landscapeView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Portrait"];
```

Will return an `id` to a `UIViewController` and you are assigning it to a `UIView`.

Comment: Ok, if I add two uiview and I assign the two id to these when I rotate the device the app crash.
Look the edit.

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x745bbe0

Comment: and then: *** First throw call stack:
(0x1aab052 0x1e87d0a 0x1aacced 0x1a11f00 0x1a11ce2 0xa3f7 0x14a5a39 0x1a76885 0x1a767a8 0x13ea1aa 0xcc4df1 0xaff8bd 0xb001f8 0xaf3aa9 0x3d1bfa9 0x1a7f1c5 0x19e4022 0x19e290a 0x19e1db4 0x19e1ccb 0x3d1a879 0x3d1a93e 0xaf1a9b 0x1f18 0x1e75)

Comment: Yeah the Hexadecimal part you can skip it... But the unrecognized selector, might say 1 thing or 2 about what you are doing. :) It should say the name of the selector you are sending...

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the observer on `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` when releasing the view controller.

The crash happens because that notification is triggered on the class which most likely has been removed from memory.